# Сохранение данных AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails

Имеется клиент-серверное приложение, где Angular (Клиент), Rails (сервер).

И для полного завершение осталось реализовать сохранение данных, т. е. если внести данные в таблицу и обновить страницу, то данные не должны теряться.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Отправлять посредством HTTP все изменения на сервер (и, по-хорошему, дожидаться от него ответа). Конкретно Ruby on Rails тут не добавляет никаких особенностей. В чём именно проблема?

Comment: GraphQL в помощь.